# Prove that the union of the two axes is a nonhomogeneous subspace of the plane

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying *Topology, An Introduction with Application to Topological Groups*, by McCarty.  Exercise D in chapter five asks, "Prove in detail that the union of the two axes is a nonhomogeneous subspace of the plane, and hence that this space could be the underlying space of no topological group.  In performing this exercise, be careful not to use a concept (such as boundedness) which is not a *topological* property of the set in question."  I think this means I can't use the notion of a supremum on the real line, since that's a "least upper **bound**," but I can't think of another way to do this.

Here's my idea of a proof.  Let $T$ be the union of the two axes, a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which I presume must have its usual topology?).  If $T$ were homogeneous, then there would exist a homeomorphism $f: T \to T$ that could (for instance) map a point $(x,0)$ on the horizontal axis to the origin $(0,0)$.  Then I will attempt to show that since $(x,0)$ has only two "arms," extending left and right on the real axis, but $(0,0)$ has four "arms," extending north, south, east and west, I cannot make a continuous bijection $f$ that sends $(x,0)$ to $(0,0)$.

[[image: Schematic of my proof using the supremum1]

Assume that such $f$ exists.  Let the "arms" next to $(x,0)$ be $L = \{ (x',0) \mid x' < x \}$ and $R = \{ (x', 0) \mid x' > x \}$, and let $N$, $S$, $E$ and $W$ be defined similarly around $(0,0)$.  Assume (WLOG) that there is a point in $L$ that maps to $N$ and a point in $L$ that maps to $E$, that is, for some $x'' < x' < x$, $f(x'',0) \in N$ and $f(x',0) \in E$.  Now let $l = \sup \{ a < x' \mid f(a,0) \in N \}$.  Again, WLOG, assume that $f(l,0) \in N$ and not $E$.  Any open neighborhood of $(l,0)$ contains points which map to both $N$ and $E$.  But since $f$ is continuous, there is an open neighborhood around $f(l,0)$ whose pre-image is a neighborhood of $(l,0)$ that maps entirely into $N$.  This is a contradiction; therefore, therefore, $f$ has to map *all* of $L$ in the vicinity of $(x,0)$ into $N$.  Similarly, $f$ has to map all of $R$ in the vicinity of $(x,0)$ into either $S$, $E$ or $W$.  The trouble is that any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ includes points in $N$, $S$, $E$ and $W$, and only two of those four arms are in the image of a neighborhood of $(x,0)$.  So, $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism.

Assuming that I've done the proof correctly, I still feel like I did not express it using topological concepts.  Given the context in the book, I'd expect that I can solve it by asserting that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff or something.  But all of my ideas hinge on finding this point $(l,0)$ whose neighborhoods all contain separated points—and I can't figure out how to prove that $(l,0)$ exists without using a supremum.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The number of connected components after removing a single point is a topological property of the space.  I haven't gone through your proof in detail, but the idea is sound.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert mentions in the comments you are using that $L$ and $R$ are connected (and correspond to the connected components of $T - (x, 0)$). To have a fully correct proof, you should also deal with the case where some of $N$, $E$, $S$, $W$ are hit by point on the $Y$ axis, or work locally near $(x, 0)$.

Homogeneity can equivalently be thought of in terms of pointed spaces, ie a tuple $(X, x_0)$ where $X$ is a topological space and $x_0 \in X$. In your case you're showing that $(T, (x,0))$ is not isomorphic to $(T, (0, 0))$ as a pointed space, for $x \ne 0$ (and by symmetry neither is $(T, (0, x))$. One of the most basic invariants of pointed spaces is the number of connected components of $X - x_0$ (or of $U - x_0$ for $U$ sufficiently small neighborhood of $x_0$).